# metodos DELETE y PUT no responden en un servidor

Tags: javascript, php, crud, xmlhttprequest

estoy desarrollando mi primera REST API con php y js. Estoy creando un editor de archivos .txt usando los métodos http de POST, GET, PUT y DELETE. Todo bien en mi servidor local, pero ya que lo subí a un hosting gratuito me sale este error al eliminar y actualizar, este problema recide de js al momento de enviar la solicitud porque ya probe mi REST API en Poostman y si funciona bien el problema es cuando lo utilizo en la web y me devuelve lo siguiente en la consola:

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

El error me lo muestra en el metodo httpDelete en http.send(); asi mismo el metodo httpPut en http.sen();

No encuentro una solución a mi problema, alguien podría ayudarme por favor.

Aquí mis métodos PUT y DELETE en js:

```
// method DELETE
function httpDelete(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("DELETE", url, true);
    http.send();

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
            var respuesta = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            if(respuesta.estado == 'eliminarArch') {
                mostrarArchActualizados(entrada = "mostrar");
                limpiar();
            }
        }
    }
}

// method PUT
function httpPut(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("PUT", url, true);
    http.send();

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
            var respuesta = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            if(respuesta.estado == 'actualizado') {
                mostrarArchActualizados(entrada = "mostrar");
                limpiar();
            }
        }
    }
}

// ELIMINAR ARCHIVO
document.getElementById('btnEliminar').addEventListener("click", function() {
    eliminarArchivo();
})
function eliminarArchivo() {

    if(document.getElementById('nomDoc').innerHTML != "") {
        httpDelete("./php/metodos.php?eliminar="+document.getElementById('nomDoc').innerHTML);
        // alert(document.getElementById('nomDoc').innerHTML);
    } else {
        alert("Seleccione un archivo para eliminar");
    }
}

// ACTUALIZAR NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO
document.getElementById('btnCambiar').addEventListener("click", function() {
    actualizarArchivo();
});
function actualizarArchivo() {
    var campo = document.getElementById('txtCambiarNom');

    if(campo.value.trim() == "") {
        alert("Llene el campo para actualizar el nombre");
    } else {
        var nom = campo.value.replace(/ /g, "_");
        httpPut("./php/metodos.php?archivo="+document.getElementById('nomDoc').innerHTML+"&actualizar="+nom);
    }
}
```

Aquí está mi php donde recibo todas las solicitudes:

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        case 'GET':
            break;
        case 'POST':
            break;
        case 'DELETE':
            if(isset($_GET['eliminar'])) {                
                if(eliminarArchivo($_GET['eliminar'])) {
                    $respuesta['estado'] = 'eliminarArch';
                    http_response_code(200);
                } else {
                    http_response_code(500);
                }

            } else {
                http_response_code(404);
            }

            break;

        case 'PUT':
            if(isset($_GET['archivo']) && isset($_GET['actualizar'])) {       

                if(actualizarArchivo($_GET['archivo'], $_GET['actualizar'])) {
                    $respuesta['estado'] = 'actualizado';
                    http_response_code(200);

                } else {
                    http_response_code(500);
                }

            } else {
                http_response_code(404);
            }

            break;

        default:

            break;
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Comment: No aparece nada mas en consola? algun otro error de red o en la consola de javascript? No aparecen depronto errores de CORS?

Comment: solo es eso lo que me sale